# Rolling back edits to remove posts from the reopen queue

Tags: support, edits, vote-to-reopen, rollbacks

I'm aware that questions that are edited within 5 days of being put on-hold are bumped into the Reopen Queue.

However, it's not clear whether rolling back the edits will remove it.

I'm curious about this as there's been a case where a user has made an insubstantial edit to a closed question, which has put it into the Reopen queue - I obviously can't tell whether they voted for it themselves, but there's strong evidence to believe they have (based on past patterns).

Comment: If they voted to reopen, then the question would be in the reopen queue anyway, edit or no edit.

Comment: @Weapon yup, but my understanding is that if the question is automatically added, it'll state that in the queue item (as it did for this question: _This question was edited after it was closed. Should it be reopened?_ or something like that), rather than just _Should this question be reopened?_ I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a rollback does not remove a post from the reopen review queue if it was entered through an edit.

Instead the review shows that the most recent edit was a rollback:

[image: rollback in review]